# Missing control knob for bathroom radiator

Tags: bathroom, radiator

I recently moved to a new house that has a bathroom radiator, but the temperature control knob is missing. The problem is that I don't know the type, brand, and model of it to search for a replacement for the knob, it only has some words and numbers on it (in the photos attached). Can someone help in identifying the model or where I could find replacements?

(I live in France)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there room to sneak a mirror up behind that switch box to see if there is additional labeling on the back side?

Comment: I tried, there is nothing there but a coil, most probably for grounding or protection

Answer (score 1):

This is a knob for a potentiometer, you should grab a caliper and measure the dimensions of the axis, and the internal dimensions of the hole. This will be a bit complex because you need something like this:

[image]

See the bit of plastic that sticks out around the back, that takes the axis. This is uncommon, most knobs would be like this:

[image]

...without the extra bit sticking out in the back. You can use one like this too, if the diameter fits inside the smaller hole around the axis, this could be easier to find.

Try "boutons pour potentiomètre" or "potentiometer knob" on aliexpress or reichelt...